# Why am I not able to ping a computer?

Tags: java, networking, ping

I have here 2 Windows systems in the same network (XP).
If I open cmd and I type

```
ping Computer2
```

I get an answer (so ping is working).
I thought I could do this with Java also, but somehow it's not working:

```
public static void ping() {

  System.out.println("Ping Poller Starts...");
  final String computer = "Computer2";

  InetAddress inet = null;
  try {
        inet = InetAddress.getByName(computer);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + computer);

  boolean status = false;
  try {
        status = inet.isReachable(5000);
  } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if (status)
  {
            System.out.println(computer + " ok");
  }
  else
  {
            System.out.println(computer + " not pingable");
  }
}
```

Always `not pingable`. With `localhost` the code is fine. But with `Computer2` I'm not able to ping - but via cmd it's working. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does InetAddress.isReachable return false, when I can ping the IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address)

Comment: Have you tried with say `www.stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: Can be many things. `isReachable()` does not even garantee to use ICMP ECHO as the `ping` command does. Try with IP instead of "Computer2". see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)

Comment: @CongXu no it's not working... just 'localhost' is working via Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are pinging the IP address or the computer name, but it could be something as simple as using "\Computer2" instead of "Computer2".

Comment: I'm pinging the Computername. With \Computer2 or in Java "\\Computer2" is not working: java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: And how about pinging the IP address?

Comment: Oh that's interesting. It's not working even with the ip. Just via cmd.

Comment: Ok your next thing to try should be pinging an external IP address that you know works (try 173.194.34.102, which is google.com).

Comment: No this is not even working via cmd. I cannot ping an adress. So 'ping www.stackoverflow.com' or 'ping google.com' is not working even via cmd. Maybe here is something wrong with the network or I dont have permissions. But as I said, I'm able to ping 'Computer2' via cmd

Comment: Ah.  Yeah that's a whole other issue by the sounds of it.  I would ask if you're connected to the internet but since you're on Stack Overflow we can assume that you are :)  Sorry I couldn't help more.