# How to check: LAN internet connection?

Tags: java, android

I have media console with LAN (cable) internet, my app is checking internet connection on the start, like this:

```
    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {

            boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
            boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
            {
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) //WIFI
                        if (ni.isConnected())  haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) //EDGE
                    if (ni.isConnected())  haveConnectedMobile = true;
                //LAN??
             }
             return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
   }
```

So, what should I add to my  `haveNetworkConnection()` function to check LAN internet connection?

Comment: You might want to check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007450/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-in-java

Comment: I think you need to ping somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_ETHERNET) states that the Type is TYPE_ETHERNET.