# How to ping a machine by its Full Computer Name in Java

Tags: java

I searched a bit here before asking this question.

```
InetAddress.getByName("SOMECONSTANTCOMPUTERNAME.xxx.CORP.xxx.COM").isReachable(10000)
```

This always returns false or 
    UnknownHostException but by using cmd and writing

```
ping SOMECONSTANTCOMPUTERNAME.xxx.CORP.xxx.COM
```

I am getting ping status.

Finally apologies if I didn't do proper research.

Regards,
icr

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does InetAddress.isReachable return false, when I can ping the IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address)

Comment: I read this before I posted, Actually these were with proper host names and IP Address. In my case ipaddress changes.

Answer (score 3):

You may be trying to get the IP address of an IPv6 address and a scope_id was specified for a global IPv6 address. As the API throws UnknownHostException only in two scenarios as mentioned here:

> **getByName**
>
> public static InetAddress getByName(String host)
>                                throws UnknownHostException Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name. The host name can
>   either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual
>   representation of its IP address. If a literal IP address is supplied,
>   only the validity of the address format is checked.
>
> For host specified in literal IPv6 address, either the form defined in
>   RFC 2732 or the literal IPv6 address format defined in RFC 2373 is
>   accepted. IPv6 scoped addresses are also supported. See here for a
>   description of IPv6 scoped addresses.
>
> If the host is null then an InetAddress representing an address of the
>   loopback interface is returned. See RFC 3330 section 2 and RFC 2373
>   section 2.5.3.
>
> **Parameters**: host - the specified host, or null.
>
> **Returns**: an IP address for the given host name.
>
> **Throws**: UnknownHostException - if no IP address for the host could be
>   found, or if a scope_id was specified for a global IPv6 address.

Learn more about IPv6 scoped address here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#scoped

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried using it, having the same problem with isReachable(), but I just used syso for getIPAddress() it returned the current Address of target machine.