# Android: ping without /system/bin/ping

Tags: android, ping, reachability

On some devices, the binary `/system/bin/ping` seems to be removed. 
When I connect the device by USB and type

```
adb shell ping
```

it says:

```
/system/bin/sh: ping: not found
```

Is it possible to still send ping requests from such devices? 
What are other alternatives to find out if a server is reachable or if packets get lost?

Answer (score 4):

What's about [InetAddress.isReachable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) ? Doc:

> Tries to reach this InetAddress. This method first tries to use ICMP
>   (ICMP ECHO REQUEST), falling back to a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo)
>   of the remote host.

Comment: This command doesn't always work. Seems to be a Java bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address

Comment: **Resolved Date:2004-09-20** [Link on bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4921816)