# How to do true pingin in java code?

Tags: java

```
InetAddress.getByName(address).isReachable(timeout);
```

I am using this line to ping, and i wonder what is the propriate timeout to ping ? 
I use 1000 but it doesn't work properly than i changed to 2000?

Comment: And did it work ith 2000? Yes: Your connection/computer is slow. No: Firewall(s)...?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address

Comment: There is a good article about isReachable method.
http://bordet.blogspot.com/2006/07/icmp-and-inetaddressisreachable.html

Comment: it worked with 2000 and it sometimes works with 1000. Is there any way to make it 1000 or less ?