# Ping an IP address or a host from .Net MAUI App

Tags: maui, ping

I have created a brand new .net MAUI App (VS 2022 Community).

I am trying to ping an IP address from my MainPage.

My code:

```cs
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(hostOrIp);

PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

However, the code above does not seem to work at all, not on Android emulator not on a physical Android device either. The requisite permissions are already taken care of. I am getting a "System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.TimedOut" reply every time even to well known IP addresses like 8.8.8.8.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I ping '127.0.0.1', it's successful. But for '8.8.8.8', it's also TimedOut. What IP address do you want to ping?

Comment: Any public IP on which ICMP is allowed.

Comment: If you ping '127.0.0.1', will it be successful or TimedOut?

Comment: YES, it is successful. Thanks.

Comment: You mean your problem has been solved?

Comment: No Sun. I can ping 127.0.0.1 successfully. Any other IP is "Request timed out".

Comment: I posted the answer. I hope it is of assistance to you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the program on emulator using any other IP, it will be TimedOut as you said:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync("47.75.18.65");
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image]

However, if I test it on real device, it will be successful.

There is another way to achieve it when run the program on emulator. You can make the ping by a Java Runtime command:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

#if ANDROID
        Java.Lang.Process p1 = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("ping -c 1 47.75.18.65");
        int returnVal = p1.WaitFor();
#endif

}
```

`returnVal` is 1 indicating success, and here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/KavY83z).

Wish these can help you.

Comment: Thanks very much Sun. I will check and get back. By the way, in my case it does not seem to work even on a real device. I will double check and get back.

Comment: By the way this should work for a host like "google.com" as well, Right?

Comment: Sorry, will check it myself. :)

Comment: *By the way this should work for a host like "google.com" as well, Right?* Yes.

Comment: Well, if i ping google.com it returns 1 which is correct. If i ping "askjdsakjfkjsdkjf.com" it returns 2, which again is correct. However, it returns 1 for even non-existent IPs like "3.3.3.3".

Comment: It returning 2 means error. I search 3.3.3.3 and find [this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=3.3.3.3+ip&qs=UT&pq=3.3.3.3&sk=LT1MT1UT2&sc=10-7&cvid=6156C51C5984423FAFC6D7D58824BED6&FORM=QBRE&sp=5&ghc=1&lq=0).

Comment: You can see this case: [Ping timeout not working in Xamarin android form application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250334/19902734). Wish it can help you.