# Internet Control Message Protocol for Java

Tags: sockets, ping, icmp, inetaddress

Pls help me guys. I end my work for one simple program. I need to check a servers status. I tried to use InetAdress.isReacheble and Socket. But sometimes if server on windows I get a server status false. After reading a lot of information, I realized that this is one of the bug of java [enter link description here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4921816). But the sources are old. Is this problem still relevant?
I tried using code this comment [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address)

```
private static boolean isReachable(String addr, int openPort, int timeOutMillis) {
try {
     // Any Open port on other machine
     // openPort =  22 - ssh, 80 or 443 - webserver, 25 - mailserver etc.
    try (Socket soc = new Socket()) {
        soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, openPort), timeOutMillis);
    }
    return true;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    return false;
}
```

If server on Windows I use port RDP (3389).
But the customer does not like. He wants me to check the status through ICMP. Is this possible?
I found the app ICMP [enter link description here](http://www.icmp4j.org/d/index.html). Tried to connect from the application library but nothing happened.
I will be grateful for any information!

Answer (score 0):

InetAddress.isReacheble by default uses icmp [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)
Pls sorry for my stupid question